# Solve ODE $y' = \frac{xy}{x^2-y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this ODE: $y' = \frac{xy}{x^2-y^2}$

My approach was to substitute $y(x) \mapsto z(x)x$. Therefore

$$
z'x-z = \frac{x^2z}{x^2(1-z^2)} = \frac{z}{1-z^2}
$$

Hence

$$
z'x = \frac{2z-z^3}{1-z^2} \implies z'\frac{1-z^2}{2z-z^3}=\frac{1}{x}
$$

Integrating both sides with respect to $x$:

$$
\int z'\frac{1-z^2}{2z-z^3} dx=\ln|x|+c
$$

And now I'm stuck.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**

As the user 00GB noticed, I started it wrong... Using the substitution $y = zx$ then $y' = z'x + z$ not $z'x - z$. That correction leads to what he stated:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{1-z^2}{z^3}dz&=\int\frac{1}{x}dx\\
\int\frac{1-z^2}{z^3}dz&=\ln|x| +C\\
\int\frac{1}{z^3}dz-\int\frac{1}{z}dz&=\ln|x| + C\\
-\frac{1}{2z^2}-\ln|z|&=\ln|x| + C
\end{align*}
$$
And substituting back $z = \frac{y}{x}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{2\frac{y^2}{x^2}}-\ln|\frac{y}{x}|&=\ln|x| + C\\
-\frac{x^2}{2y^2}&=\ln|\frac{y}{x}|+\ln|x| + C\\
x^2&=y^2(C -2\ln|y|)\\
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started from your solution
$$
z'x+z = \frac{x^2z}{x^2(1-z^2)} = \frac{z}{1-z^2}
$$
then
$$xz'=\frac{z^3}{1-z^2}$$
$$\frac{1-z^2}{z^3} \text{dz}=\frac{1}{x}\text{dz}$$
Integrate both side and then you are done

Comment: My solution started with $z'x - z$ not $x'z + z$. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Bruno Reis,  you can not just stared with $y=xz(x)$

Comment: Oh.... My bad! I'll edit it then. Thanks

Comment: @BrunoReis, if you found my answer helping you, please vote for it . Thank you

Answer (score 2):

$$y' = \frac{xy}{x^2-y^2}$$
$$x^2-y^2 = {xx'y}$$
Substitute $u=x^2$:
$$u-y^2=\dfrac y 2u'$$
$$yu'-2u=-2y^2$$
$$ \left (\dfrac u {y^2} \right)'=-\dfrac 2y$$
Integrate.
$$x^2=y^2(C-2 \ln y)$$

Answer (score 1):

Others have already noticed that your equation is incorrect. Anyway, here's how you evaluate this integral
$$
\int \frac{1-z^2}{2z-z^3} dz=\int \frac{2-z^2}{2z-z^3} dz
- \int \frac{1}{2z-z^3} dz=\int \frac{1}{z} dz
- \int \frac{1}{z^3(\frac{2}{z^2}-1)} dz
$$

Put $\frac{2}{z^2}-1=t$ for the second integral and you are done

Comment: Nice! But then I'll need to use the product rule for integration since I have all these multiplied by $z'$ right?

Comment: @BrunoReis $z'=dz/dx$ you can notice the dx will get cancelled

Comment: Oh, never mind... I was going for separable equations, so $z'=dz/dx$ is what I actually need to use that! Thank you!